# Creating a Position with Defined Possibilities within N Ply (for engine testing)

Tags: engines, puzzles, composing

### DEFINITIONS

The definitions of "cook" and "dual" I'm using (which are the standard definitions if I understand them correctly) are:

```
Cook: A position where the attacking side, on their first move, has more than one move available that will lead to mate in N

Dual: A position where the attacking side, on their second move or on a later move, has more than one move available that will lead to mate in N
```

### GOAL

I would like to construct a position with **white** to move such that specific possibilities exist within **5 ply**. 5 ply was chosen since it's the lowest ply count that allows for the existence of duals. It is desirable to keep the ply count as low as possible to minimize search time.

This is for the purpose of engine testing.

The specific possibilities I'd like the position to have are shown below. All possible white first moves are grouped into one of four mutually exclusive categories.

### CATEGORY 1: WHITE FORCES MATE IN 3 (5 ply)

```
1. w00 b00 2. w01 b01 3. w02# (principal variation)
       b02 2. w03 b03 3. w04# (this line makes this position a dual since white **does have** multiple choices to force mate: 2. w03 and 2. w05)
              w05 b04 3. w06# (this line makes this position a dual since white **does have** multiple choices to force mate: 2. w03 and 2. w05)

1. w15 b11 2. w16 b12 3. w17# (this line does not make this position a dual since white **does not have** multiple choices to force mate)
                  b13 3. w18# (this line does not make this position a dual since white **does not have** multiple choices to force mate)

1. w07 b05 2. w08 b06 3. w09# (this line makes this position a cook since white has multiple first moves to force mate: 1. w00 and 1. w07)
```

So, overall, the position I'm trying to construct is both cooked and has duals. This is as desired for test purposes.

### CATEGORY 2: WHITE BLUNDER ALLOWS BLACK TO FORCE MATE IN EITHER 2 PLY OR 4 PLY

```
1. w10 b07 2. w11 b08# (w10 allows black to force mate in 2)

1. w12 b09# (w12 allows black to force mate in 1)
```

### CATEGORY 3: FORCED DRAW (either by stalemate or by the 50-move rule)

```
1. w13 b10 2. w14 1/2-1/2 (b10 puts black in a position where nothing white does can cause black to not be stalemated)

OR

1. w19 b14 2. w20 1/2-1/2 (w20 increases the half-move counter to 100; this is a draw by the 50-move rule)
```

### CATEGORY 4: WHITE FIRST MOVES THAT DO NOT LEAD TO FORCED WIN, LOSS, OR DRAW WITHIN 5 PLY

This section contains any other white moves that are necessary to allow the mate in 3, loss, and draw lines above. The number of white moves in this section should be as small as possible. Ideally, there would be no white moves in this section, but that may be too difficult to achieve, so the possibility is allowed.

### MY QUESTION

I am finding constructing a position with these possibilities to be a challenging task.

Are there techniques, other than trial and error, for creating positions with specific possibilities that may be practically performed by hand? I suppose the general solution would be computer-based retrograde analysis (which I am not in a position to implement).